# Why Char value of integer converted to string is different many a times

Tags: apex

I have a method is getting integers as parameters, below is the code

```
public Integer findChars(integer x, integer y, integer z){
    1# system.debug('initial integer'+ x + ' '+ y + ' '+ z);
    string s = string.valueOf(x)+string.valueOf(y)+string.valueOf(z);
    Integer[] chars = s.getChars();
    2# system.debug('char values '+ chars[0] + chars[1] + chars[2]);
    return (chars[0]+chars[1]+chars[2]);
    
}
```

below is the debug of the transaction
1. here 0 -1 1 is having 48, 45, 49 respectively

[image]

2. below  1, -1, 0 is having 49, 45, 49. So 0 is having different char value

[image]

**Purpose** - I am creating a set of the sum of these 3 to avoid duplicate triplets.

As a result of different char values of 0, the sum is changed. As a result duplicate triplets are coming in the list.
[image]

Please help me out to understand this behaviour. Am I missing something over here? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you converting to a string to detect duplicates? Surely it is better to simply compare integer arrays?

Comment: A `Set<Integer[]>` would allow you to track the integer combinations your code has seen.

Comment: The error is here: `0 -1 1 is having 48, 45, 49 respectively`. You have 4 characters in that string and `45` is the code of just `-`, it isn't the code of `-1` (because they are 2 chars). As Phil said a Set would be the best option to avoid duplicate triplets like `[-1, 0, 1]` and `[1, -1, 0]`

Comment: Thanks @PhilW for pointing in a direction. I will check it out.

Comment: Thanks, @RubenDG for the clarification. Yes, Phil's answer I will implement.

Comment: Hi @PhilW it is not working.  Set<Integer[]> is coming like this - {(-1, 0, 1), (0, -1, 1), (1, -1, 0), (2, -1, -1)}.

Comment: If order is not to be checked, then use a `Set<Set<Integer>>`.